# Implementation of Optimistic Locking in Database Updates

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, versioning, optimistic-locking

I have a requirement in my application where before updating a record in db I want to be sure that record isn't updated by another user. I know how to implement optimistic locking by having a version identifier in the entity and that will take care of it.

```
@Transactional
public void updateProductApprover(Long productId, String currentLoggedInUser) {
    Product product = productRepository.findById(productId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Product not found"));
    // if updation done by another user, then save will automatically throw exception
 
    product.setApprovedBy(currentLoggedInUser);
    productRepository.save(product);
}
```

So in above scenerion after product is fetched if any updation happens in product data in db, save will get failed with `OptimisticLockException` and that's fine.

What if view product UI page is opened on my screen and I take 2-3 min time to send update request and meanwhile another user updates something.How it's going to work ?

My assumption is that while loading the view product page, I have to load the identifier as well and send that in the update request. In the backend I have to match that with the db row version. If it's doesn't match I will ask user to refresh product page and send the update request again.

So it will be mostly a compination of :

1. Explicitly implemented by my App by sending version in update request from UI page and validation against db as request will only be sending id to update and there's no way it will check for version implicitly before updation.
2. Implicitly implemented by JPA when my updation happened after updateProductPrice start getting executed and product fetched from db.

Please suggest If I am missing something.

Regards,

Comment: Not sure what the question is here. What you have is only going to guard against concurrent modifications from the time you read the entity from the DB to when you call Save - so just within the updateProductApprover method. If you want to guard for longer, REST apps are known to serialize the entity (and the version data), and have the full modified object sent back to be used in the save call. If you aren't doing that, it is up to you to check what ever data you send in against the entity you get from the find call.

Comment: @Chris but if you see the method, it accepts only productId to approve the product. Check what I needed is that Approver is taking action on the same product details and it has not been modified in background. My understanding from your comment is that I have to take product row version in the method call to implement it. is that right ?

Comment: That is the way of stateless REST api- PUT operations will overwrite what is there. You need some version indicator or something to reference the expected state as well as your changed data to make sure you aren't overwriting something that has changed out from under you; pretty much the same as optimistic locking for the entity, but you have to handle REST operations yourself. It doesn't have to be a version field - you could just pass in an old and new value if that is all you care about for the current operation.